# R: Replace "+" character with gsub

Tags: r, operator-keyword, gsub

the question seems totally trivial but I cannot figure out why it isn't working. I simply want to replace a character variable involving a "+" operator with a single value excluding the "+" operator. For some reason gsub() and sub() function replace the number value but keep the operator. Any hint on how this can be overcome?
Many thanks!

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,"5+")
gsub(pattern="5+",replacement="5",x=data)
#[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5+"

gsub(pattern="5+",replacement="",x=data)
#[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "+"
```

R 3.0.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`+` is a metacharacter, and needs to be escaped when you want to match it:

```
gsub(pattern="5\\+",replacement="5",x=data)
#[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

Or more generally, if you want to remove the `+`:

```
gsub(pattern="\\+",replacement="",x=data)
```

If unescaped, `+` means "The preceding item will be matched one or more times", so in your second example, the `"5"` element of `"5+"` is matched by the pattern, and replaced by `""`, leaving you with `"+"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking it must be sth with the concept of operators/metacharacters in R.

Comment: You can also `gsub( pattern="+" , "" , fixed = TRUE , x = data )` for the pattern to be treated as literal.

Answer (score 4):

Use `fixed=TRUE` option:

`gsub(pattern="+", replacement="", fixed=TRUE, c(1,2,3,4,"5+"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `strsplit`:

```
as.numeric(strsplit(data, "\\+"))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```